# Deciphering a particular SELinux/AVC error

Tags: selinux

This SELinux avc error ( as generated by `ausearch` ) has me confused.

```
time->Fri Nov 13 16:04:49 2015
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1447452289.136:242): proctitle="/opt/firefox/firefox"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1447452289.136:242): arch=c000003e syscall=9 success=yes exit=140443907256320 a0=0 a1=10000 a2=7 a3=22 items=0 ppid=3742 pid=4212 auid=4294967295 uid=1000 gid=1000 euid=1000 suid=1000 fsuid=1000 egid=1000 sgid=1000 fsgid=1000 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="firefox" exe="/opt/firefox/firefox" subj=system_u:system_r:initrc_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1447452289.136:242): avc:  denied  { execmem } for  pid=4212 comm="firefox" scontext=system_u:system_r:initrc_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:initrc_t:s0 tclass=process permissive=1
```

I do a `whereis` on firefox, and am told it is at `/usr/bin/firefox`. This is a symbolic link to `/opt/firefox/firefox`. Furthermore checking the context of firefox I find:

```
 # ls -Z /usr/bin/firefox 
 system_u:object_r:bin_t:SystemLow /usr/bin/firefox
 # ls -Z /opt/firefox/firefox
 system_u:object_r:usr_t:SystemLow /opt/firefox/firefox
```

So where did the `initrc_t` come from?

Also, what are the subject and target? I'm pretty sure the subject is `/opt/firefox/firefox` but given the context, I'm having doubts.
What the target is I am totally in the dark on.

Furthermore, what is `execmem` in this context? (For that matter, the message says `syscall=9`. Where can I find out what syscall numbers map to what?) Google only shows it appearing in avc errors.

I would prefer an answer to better figure out avc errors, rather then a specific answer for this problem.

Comment: I appreciate people who come in and clean up the formatting of my posts, and clean up my typos. I do not appreciate "karma-gluttens" who rather then clean up my posts, change my posts while even ignoring the typos that I made. ( Guess this question will be closed now, for pissing off a karma-glutten. )

Comment: No, the question will not be closed and yes, the edit was a bad one. In the user's defense, I should point out that there is no "karma" (reputation) awarded for editing after reaching 2k rep, so it was an honest mistake, nothing more. The user probably missed the other mistakes because he isn't a native English speaker. In the future, it would be better if you'd give the people who edit your posts the benefit of the doubt. They have nothing to gain from it and are doing it to improve the site.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ausearch -i`, then the `-i` will "interpret" the syscalls so they are more useful to people.  Syscall 9 is "mmap", which makes sense based on the execmem denial (which appears to happen when SELinux stops a process from creating a writeable or executable memory region).  It's a good idea to stop that - but if it absolutely has to be enabled, you do that by setting the `allow_execstack` boolean to true.

The `initrc_t` is the target of the running user, not the file being run.  It looks from the audit message like Firefox might be being launched from an init script here (based on the initrc_t, the audit UID being `-1` - AKA "uninitialized", and on there being no TTY).

I assume this problem has gone away by now, probably by SELinux being disabled; that seems to be how people usually fix weird SELinux issues. :)  But here's an answer to get the next person started anyway.